# Increment Alphabet Python

Tags: python

I have a list like this

```
['AX95', 'BD95']
```

I need to expand the list starting from `AX95` to `BD95` like this

```
['AX95', 'AY95', 'AZ95', 'BA95','BB95','BC95','BD95']
```

My current code works fine for single alphabets like

```
['A95', 'D95']
```

My code looks like this for now,

```
import re


def resolve(item):
    start = int(re.search(r'\d+', item[0]).group())
    end = int(re.search(r'\d+', item[1]).group())
    print(item)
    c = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+', item[0]).group()
    d = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+', item[1]).group()
    print(c, d)
    for char in range(ord(c), ord(d) + 1):
        yield chr(char) + str(end)


xx = resolve(['AX95', 'BD95'])

print(list(xx))
```

How to do this?

Comment: Split this down into smaller problems, rather than trying to tackle it all in one function; for one thing, you have unnecessary repetition in your current code.

Comment: Do you mean only expand by the left two bit `[A-Z]` specified?

Comment: Yes. The start and end range are specified.

Comment: I don't think its clear what you're trying to do. Could you try to explain what output you would expect better.

Comment: Input `['AX95', 'BD95']` . I need output like this `['AX95', 'AY95', 'AZ95', 'BA95','BB95','BC95','BD95']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly use `ord()` on multiple characters , it would error out with the error -

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

Also , it would be very complicated to do this with `for` loop and `range()` , I would suggest using `while` loop and checking till the start characters become the end characters.

One way to do this would be to get the last element, check if its `Z` change it to `A` and increment the element before it. Otherwise take its `ord()` increment by `1` and then get that character using `chr()` .

Example Algorithm that works on arbitrary size of characters -

```
def resolve(item):
    start = int(re.search(r'\d+', item[0]).group())
    c = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+', item[0]).group()
    d = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+', item[1]).group()
    print(c, d)
    s = c
    yield s + str(start)
    while s != d:
        ls = len(s) - 1
        news = ""
        for i in range(ls,-1,-1):
            c = s[i]
            if c.upper() == 'Z':
                news += 'A'
            else:
                news += chr(ord(c) + 1)
                break
        s = s[:i] + news[::-1]
        yield s + str(start)
```

Example/Demo -

```
>>> def resolve(item):
...     start = int(re.search(r'\d+', item[0]).group())
...     c = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+', item[0]).group()
...     d = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+', item[1]).group()
...     print(c, d)
...     s = c
...     yield s + str(start)
...     while s != d:
...         ls = len(s) - 1
...         news = ""
...         for i in range(ls,-1,-1):
...             c = s[i]
...             if c.upper() == 'Z':
...                 news += 'A'
...             else:
...                 news += chr(ord(c) + 1)
...                 break
...         s = s[:i] + news[::-1]
...         yield s + str(start)
...
>>>
>>> xx = resolve(['AX95', 'BD95'])
>>>
>>> print(list(xx))
AX BD
['AX95', 'AY95', 'AZ95', 'BA95', 'BB95', 'BC95', 'BD95']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are :)

```
import re

def resolve(item):
    print (item)
    num = int(re.search(r'\d+', item[0]).group())
    p11 = re.search(r'(\w)(\w)', item[0]).group(1)
    p12 = re.search(r'(\w)(\w)', item[0]).group(2)
    p21 = re.search(r'(\w)(\w)', item[1]).group(1)
    p22 = re.search(r'(\w)(\w)', item[1]).group(2)
    print (p11, p12, p21, p22)  
    for word in range(ord(p11), ord(p21) + 1):
        for word2 in range(ord(p12) if ord(p11) == word else ord('A'), (ord(p22) if ord(p21) == word else ord('Z')) + 1):
            yield chr(word) + chr(word2) + str(num)
```

Comment: same "for"(for word2..) you can repeat for numbers in 3 and 4th position

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach which should also cope with roll over.

It works by first splitting out the letters and numbers from the start and end ranges. The two letter groups are then converted to base 27 numbers. The aim is to then simply count from start to end.

Python's `itertools.product` is then used to create a sequence of `AA` to `ZZ` with a `itertools.islice` providing the necessary range.

Why base 27? This was a workaround similar to dealing with leading zeros. i.e. converting `AA` and `AAA` to base 26 would give the same value.

```
import string, itertools, re

def convert_to_range(chars):
    value = 0
    for index, unit in enumerate([ord(x) - 64 for x in reversed(chars)]):
        value += unit * (27 ** index)
    return value

def resolve(item):
    start_split = re.split("(\d+)", item[0])
    end_split = re.split("(\d+)", item[1])
    trailing = end_split[1]
    start = convert_to_range(start_split[0])
    end = convert_to_range(end_split[0])
    cols = [' '+string.ascii_uppercase] * len(end_split[0])

    for x in itertools.islice(itertools.product(*cols), start, end+1):
        step = "".join(x).lstrip(" ")
        if ' ' in step:
            continue
        yield step + trailing

print(list(resolve(['AX95', 'BD95'])))
print(list(resolve(['X95', 'AA95'])))
print(list(resolve(['ZX95', 'AAB95'])))
```

This would give you:

```
['AX95', 'AY95', 'AZ95', 'BA95', 'BB95', 'BC95', 'BD95']
['X95', 'Y95', 'Z95', 'AA95']
['ZX95', 'ZY95', 'ZZ95', 'AAA95', 'AAB95']
```